# Prevent react-router-redux from updating the history

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am using react-router-redux, how do I prevent the history from updating whenever I click a link. For example when I am on the about page (the link to which is defined in the Navbar), If I navigate to the about page and click the about link again this updates the route history, so that I have to press back twice to go back to the previous page. If I click the about link 10 times, I will have to press back 11 times to back to the previous page (the first 10 times I press the back button nothing happens).

Many thanks

Comment: have you tried using [replace](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/replace-bool)?